# Grid desktop icon in ubuntu

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

I'm an old member of ubuntu from ubuntu 16.04

I have a big problem in Ubuntu desktops from many years ago and in ubuntu 16.04 releases until now that i have Ubuntu 20.04. and that is "Desktop icons grid". as you know grid system of Ubuntu desktop is like all of linux distributions and is not like of windows (Windows operating system) that you could set them regularly and below on each other with a specific size

if you're an Ubuntu desktop user so you know what is my mean
in Ubuntu you can put 1000 icons in a one point of desktop. for example: x:1 - y:1 and you can set them below on each other
but windows is not this way. in windows every square (32px, 32px) is only for a icon and icons are set regulary and below on each other. very regulary and in a parallel line

How can i change ubuntu desktops (20.04) icons grid like windows ?

i wanna my Ubuntu desktops (20.04) icons change to windows style

Comment: In 20.04 the desktop icons should "snap to grid". Are you saying that you DON'T want the desktop icons to "snap to grid"?

Comment: @darth_epoxy hi and tnx because of you kind. do you work with windows ? the windows desktop grid is not free to move icons everywhere you want. for example in ubuntu you can you put 1000 icons in on point (e.g. x:1, y:1) but in windows you counldn't do this

Comment: I still don't see if you're meaning Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop using Unity 7 as used in Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, or you mean the now default GNOME desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Ubuntu 20.04 has many desktop choices available).  *I've removed reference to members, I didn't see "AmirAli" nor "Esteki" in searches of Ubuntu membership roles on lp*

Comment: @guiverc when i told i'm a member of ubuntu from 16.04 my mean wasn't i was in developer team (do you're tired ? because actully dont get my mean) my mean was i use ubuntu desktops from when ubuntu release version of 16.04 until now ! and can you don't touch my post anymore ? let another users solve my problem when your self cant !

Comment: The quality of your post was low, and my attempts/edits were to improve quality so it's not closed & users of this site get a chance to understand and answer it.  I don't see your name on https://launchpad.net/~ubuntumembers/+members so the member detail looks wrong.   *I'm not a developer either, but membership is more than just devs*

Comment: @guiverc i use ubuntu desktop from 2016 and with version of 16.04 until now and in this years i use ubuntu with a single email only: kaperco777@yahoo.com. and about ubnutu, it's an open source and free operating system so the users do not have to register they names in any site or community as an ubuntu member. it's right ? there is many people that you and ubuntu developer team dont known them but they use ubuntu !

Comment: In the Ubuntu community, the term *member* has a special meaning (someone who has made a *significant and substantial* contribution to the project; membership being a *reward*), be it development, documentation, art, or many different ways. Your use of the term implies you've contributed in that way, wearing a *badge* you've not earned. I believe you'll get better responses without mentioning *member* (why I removed it) as you risk annoying the more *skilled* people here... but I've changed it once already...  ps:  this is a user support site, *user* is a badge that is prized here too!

Comment: @guiverc i don't think other people think like you
"i'm a an old member of ubuntu": mean someone that use ubuntu products from many years ago and is in community of ubuntu users